# jQuery function only works on reload

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following very simple code snippet which is loaded from a separate file into one jQuery Mobile page in a multi-page site that I am building:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="state_choice"]').change(function(){
        var thisState = $(this).val();
        var indexState = '#' + thisState;
        $('.state').hide();
            $(indexState).show();
      });
})
```

It was working but now it only works when I reload the page. I was examining the page load with Firebug and it was not consistently loading the jQuery file because this link was not showing up until reload.

```
<script src="inc/jquery/belmont.custom.js"></script>
```

Typically the console will show when a new page is called in jQuery mobile but I did find that this particular page did not always show up in the console log when a link to it was clicked. I have tested on a desktop simulator (Dashcode's iOS Simulator), in desktop browsers (FF and Safari) and on my iPhone all with the same results.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior? How can I make sure that this works consistently?

EDIT: I have changed the code to use bind as follows:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    $('select[name="state_choice"]').change(function(){
        var thisState = $(this).val();
        var indexState = '#' + thisState;
        $('.state').hide();
        $(indexState).show();
    });
})
```

I have added console.log(indexState) to the function and this does not fire consistently either.

And I actually mis-spoke earlier - this is a mobile site consisting of single pages. Do I have to load the jQuery custom function script into every page? Or can I just load it into the one in question?

Comment: I was able to get it sorted out. First the custom js file must be loaded right after the jQuery core file. Second, it is better to use $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {.... than it is to use the ready method.

Comment: After reviewing again this morning it seems that the problem still exists. Sometimes you are required to reload the page, others it works right out of the gate. I have updated the code above to reflect the changes that I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it sorted out. Since jQM loads each subsequent page with AJAX you need to treat interactions like this like any other dynamically loaded element. Changing `bind()` to `on()` (I am using jQuery 1.7+) gets everything working like it should:

```
$('body').on('pageinit', '#id_of_page_using_function', function(){
    $('select[name="state_choice"]').change(function(){
        var thisState = $(this).val();
        var indexState = '#' + thisState;
        $('.state').hide();
        $(indexState).show();
    });
})
```